# Log-Log histogram with custom bins

Tags: plotting

Using:

```
Histogram[list, {"Log", 10}, {"Log", "Count"}]
```

I get a log-log histogram, while usign

```
Histogram[list,{{bin list}}]
```

I get a histogram with custom bins.

But how do I combine them? The naive:

```
Histogram[list,{"Log",10},{"Log","Count"},{{bin list}}]
```

gives errors.

Comment: try `SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomReal[10^5, 10^4];binlist={1, 20000, 50000, 75000, 100000};
Histogram[list, {"Log", {binlist}}, {"Log",   "Count"}]`?

Comment: @kglr it works thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `binlims` is your custom bin limits, you can use

```
Histogram[list, {"Log", {binlims}}, {"Log", "Count"}]
```